# Tag review: [tag:unmanned-aerial-vehicle], [tag:drones]

Tags: support, status-completed

Do we really need an [unmanned-aerial-vehicle](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unmanned-aerial-vehicle) and a [drones](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drones) tag as well?

Both of the tags are used once, at the same [question](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/257/are-drones-considered-part-of-the-iot-by-any-officials). I think one of them should be the other one's synonym.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have [proposed synonymisation](https://iot.stackexchange.com/tags/drones/synonyms) of [drones](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drones) and [unmanned-aerial-vehicle](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unmanned-aerial-vehicle), however there is only one user eligible to create and vote on synonyms for the [drones](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drones) tag: myself, so the community is currently unable to handle the issue by itself.

---

Since I am now a moderator, I have just approved this.

Comment: Yes, I know that currently the community do not have enough voters. But we can make to-do-lists to our future moderators. ^^

Comment: Time to cross out some items from the list. ;)

Comment: @BenceKaulics The synonyms have been approved.